# Python: Validate if column entries match a desired format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, lambda

I am currently running sanity checks to validate if an id matches the desired format. I'd like to filter my Dataframe for projects, which are not fulfilling a desired set of standard format.
In this case:

- The first two have to be letters
- The total length should be 16 characters

I'd like to find any project not matching these criteria above.

```
>>> data = [['US-T-2018-08-110','Forward'],['EU-U-2001-04-019','Backward'],['EU-U-2017-05-178','Still'], ['N/A','Up'],['DE-T-1999-08-8512','Down']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['project_id', 'name']) 
>>> df

project_id         name
US-T-2018-08-110   Forward
EU-U-2001-04-019   Backward
EU-U-2017-05-178   Still
N/A                Up
DE-T-1999-08-8512  Down
```

Should result in:

```
project_id         name
N/A                Up
DE-T-1999-08-8512  Down
```

Moreover, is there a way to achieve this without looping?

Comment: The total length of what exactly? None of the strings have 14 characters

Comment: @DaniMesejo hey sorry, forgot to include the first to letters - should be 16 in length - corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for get length and [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test if first 2 values are letters with regex `^` for start of string, `[a-aA-Z]` letters and `{2}` for length `2`:

```
m = (df['project_id'].str.len().ne(16) | 
     ~df['project_id'].str.contains('^[a-zA-Z]{2}', na=False))
df = df[m]
print (df)
          project_id  name
3                N/A    Up
4  DE-T-1999-08-8512  Down
```

What working same like inverted mask:

```
m1 = (df['project_id'].str.len().eq(16) & 
      df['project_id'].str.contains('^[a-zA-Z]{2}', na=False))
df = df[~m1]
print (df)
          project_id  name
3                N/A    Up
4  DE-T-1999-08-8512  Down
```

Thank you, @Jon Clements for improve solution for check if next `14` values after first 2 letters:

```
df = df[~df['project_id'].str.match('[a-zA-Z]{2}.{14}$', na=False)]
#alternative
#df = df[~df['project_id'].str.contains('^[a-zA-Z]{2}.{14}$', na=False)]
print (df)
          project_id  name
3                N/A    Up
4  DE-T-1999-08-8512  Down
```

Comment: Since you're doing a regex match anyway, you might as well have that also check the length is correct, so your mask just becomes `m = ~df['project_id'].str.match('[a-zA-Z]{2}.{14}$')`

Comment: If you're not going to use `.str.match` then you'll need to anchor your regex, eg: `^'[a-zA-Z]{2}.{14}$` else `.str.contains` will consider things like: `XXXXXXXUS-T-2018-08-110` to be valid...

Comment: @JonClements - I am not very good in regex, so why is used `'` here? Thank you.

Comment: It's a typo... was supposed to be `'^`.... where `^` indicates to anchor to the start of the string (the default for `.str.match`) similar to how `$` anchors to the end of a string...

Answer (score 2):

Use a [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), like the following:

```
mask = ~df['project_id'].str.match("^[a-zA-Z]{2}") | df['project_id'].str.len().ne(16)
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
          project_id  name
3                N/A    Up
4  DE-T-1999-08-8512  Down
```

The [str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) function does the following, from the documentation:

> Determine if each string starts with a match of a regular expression.

Then the regular expression pattern `^[a-zA-Z]{2}` checks that the two first characters of a string are letters.

Answer (score 1):

check if the total length is 16 or first two characters ar not letters:

```
print(df[(df['project_id'].apply(lambda x: len(x) != 16)) | (df['project_id'].apply(lambda x: not x[0:2].isalpha()))])
```